# Get a random record from a huge database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, web, random

I have to make a small app or webapp (java) can get a random record from a db which has 2 mil records. Can someone give me a suggestion how to do this ?

Each of my record look like : CA0002310032 or TD0002110099. Sorry my English is not good. Thank you.

Edit : here is some records

[image]

Comment: your English is great, yet you need to provide more info

Comment: @KickButtowski : I haved edit my question. Thank for reading